# ¿Cómo se resuelve el error: The following object is masked from ‘package?

Tags: r, rstudio

al descargar un paquete por ejemplo  lmer sale como error: "The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’: step". debo descargar el paquete step?

Answer (score 1):

#### Cuidado con este mensaje

> The following object is masked from package

Lo que nos esta indicando es que al cargar cierto paquete hay una o más funciones de este cuyo nombre es el mismo de otra función cargada desde un paquete anterior. En tu ejemplo, cando cargas `lmer` este incluye la función `step` que tiene el mismo nombre de una función ya cargada en el paquete base `stats`

#### ¿Puedo simplemente ignorar estos errores?

No, no se deberían ignorar a menos que uno este seguro que no se estén usando las funciones en conflicto. Que tengan el mismo nombre no significa que hagan lo mismo ni mucho menos que tengan los mismos parámetros. En tu ejemplo, si tuvieras un script que usara la función `stats::step()`, cuando cargues el paquete `lmer` estarás enmascarando esta función y reemplazándola por otra que hace algo totalmente distinto, con suerte tendrás un error que no te va a indicar el verdadero problema y en el peor de los casos, hasta podrías tener resultados totalmente inesperados.

Recuerda que cuando existieran estos conflictos y no hubiera forma de resolverlos, digamos, necesitas `step()` del paquete `stats` pero además necesitas las funciones de `lmer`, puedes optar por usar la forma explícita de llamar a cualquier función `paquete::función` es decir, en el caso de `step()` que fue enmascarado por el paquete `lmer` podrías modifcar tu código e invocarlo como `stats::step()`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la respuesta y sugerencia Patricio

Answer (score 0):

Cuando dice: "The following object is masked from ‘package: xx, quiere decir que el paquete que yo deseo descargar ya esta incluido dentro de otro paquete que ya estaba instalado. No afecta en ejecutar el comando.